# Problem on how to solve a situation with dragons

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development

I am the DM of a very chaotic group, which ended up in a very strange situation. Currently I am having a very hard struggle on how to DM this and how to solve this more or less in a group friendly way (not every character should die).

Following situation:
When travelling the world, the group found an adult green dragon which was sleeping in his lair. They somehow (rolled multiple 20s) managed to sneak up to the dragon and steal a Deck of Many Things from the dragon. They also managed to escape, but the dragon, sleeping here for a long time, noticed. He let them escape on purpose, just to stop then in front the entrance. He took a lot of loot from them as well as the Deck of Many Things and forced them into a quest for him: They should kill a young red dragon which is slowly gaining power in the area. He grabbed the group of 3 and dropped them right in front of the lair entrance to the young red dragon's lair.

The group entered and fought thier way all the way down. After some struggles and unforseen events they ended up in front of the young red dragon. The dragon, young und unexpirenced, was not eager to kill them but they started the fight, which ended up very, very bad (1 died, the other 2 are nearly dead which no spell slots left). In I don't know what billiant flash of mindblowing idea, they started to offer a lot of gold, juwels and their magical items to the young red dragon. The flattered dragon took the treasure and wanted to know why they are in his lair, trying to kill him.

After another 20 for persuasion they managed to convince the dragon, that someone in a near town wanted them to clear the cave from marauders. The young unexpirenced dragon took the bait and is now on its way to the city for revenge. He grabbed the nearly naked druid and flew of with him.

Meanwhile the surving cleric escaped the cave on its own just to find himself in front of the adult green dragon which gave them the "quest" to kill the dragon. After a short conversation and failed tries to convince him that they succeeded and that he is the last survivor, the green dragon is just on the edge of killing the cleric which his dragon breath. The cleric is at below 20 hp which should be a kill.
Right before exhaling, the red rival leaves the the lair and encounters the green dragon.

Now my problem: How can I solve this situation, that the group or at least on of them escapes and the dragons are not a problem anymore. My first idea was that both dragons, eager for more influence, power an might, start to fight till one dies (which should be the young red dragon (already not at full HP, breath not ready). But this opens the cave for looting and gaining their stuff back, which I consider a big punishment for ending up in this situation. I also don't want to award them a lot of XP for encountering both dragons...

I would be glad for any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want them to escape and the dragon not be a problem anymore? This post has "awesome story with deeply involved characters" written all over it.

Comment: If the all die, the campaign ends an the group is hooked for it. The dragon can still be a problem in the future like a boss encounter but currently both dragons are way to hard for them to kill or deal with them. I would like to give the players an opportunity to play the campain.

Comment: What level is the group?

Comment: They are all level 4 - 5

Comment: They are all very hooked and one player of them will be the cause of the problem why they are on this campaign. Action in his past lead to those events of destruction and marauding, but currently they dont know. So for the campaign to end, at least one character must survive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Give the characters a fair break

You have these goals:

- Let the PCs survive in a believable way
- Do not reward them for their foolhardyness of taking on the dragons

Just to frame this: An adult green dragon is CR 15, worth 13,000 XP. The encounter XP budget for a group of 3 level 4-5 characters is about 1,500 to 3,300 XP for a Deadly encounter, so that green dragon is somewhere between 4 and 9 times the budget for Deadly. Even the young red is CR 10, 5,900 XP and probably more than twice deadly.  It is clear that neither of these dragons is a fair matchup for a level 4-5 group of three.

**The only real misstep they did was trying to steal from the adult green dragon** (not attack it, mind you). That may have been a bit foolhardy. And you already had them pay their dues by taking a lot of loot of them. Everything else, it seems to me, they did do a great job on, even willingly giving up treasure and magic items when in dire straights -- which is super unfun and hard to do.

**The situation is a problem you created yourself**. Putting them to the task of killing the red dragon, on top of whatever you put in his lair for "fighting their way down" that already depleted their resources is kind of your mistake, not theirs -- you sent them into a double-Deadly fight with drained resources and no alternative due to a TPK adult green dragon on the other end of it. So you need to fix it, it is really not their fault.

**Players often will not do what you expect**. You thought they would talk with the red dragon and escape through a secret, second exit (as you disclosed in the comments, and maybe should add to the question). However, they were in a high-stress situation, had been told they need to kill the young red by a bigger dragon that already caught them when they were trying to slink away before, *and* they just had slaughtered whatever the red dragon's other defenses were, certainly not endearing them to it. It's not surprising they tried to get the jump on the dragon in this situation by attacking it while it was talking. Also in general, it is not a great idea to expect the characters to do something very specific to get out of a situation -- players have a strong tendency to come up with all kinds of plans that are not what you had in mind. There is a [three-clue rule](https://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/1118/roleplaying-games/three-clue-rule) that you should provide at least three different clues to the players if you want them to do something, and even then, you cannot rely on them doing it.

You can resolve this by having the green dragon kill the red dragon, which it wanted to do anyways, and then claim the red dragon's hoard for its own, and sending of the characters on yet another mission to give them a "last chance" to undo their mistakes.

The green dragon has demonstrated before that it is willing to do that, so it is credible it might do so again. And the green dragon should be easily able to win the fight against the red. The players will still have been made to pay for their audacity, and will not gain the red dragons hoard for free, but they will survive.

That mission can be one that puts them on track for the rest of the main campaign.

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake to leading them in this direction. The first encounter was planned with the green one, but he was asleep so my assumption was that they will leave early, as they were a lot of clear signs, like dead bodies, even a sign in front of th entrance written by another adventurer. I totally like your idea and I think I will play it this way. I've also will award them some exp because in the end they manged to fight against the red dragon and somehow survive. This should make up for some exp i guess. Thank you very much for you idea. Sounds very reasonable.

Comment: Same for the red dragon. I, as an unexpirenced dm, thought that when the dragon started to talk to the group instead of straight trying to kill them, they would have a conversation and a chance to leave thorugh a 2nd entrance and escape both dragons unharmed and with some offered  gold or something.

Comment: @glethien To distil it to the essentials "*I [...] thought that [...] [the group] would have a conversation*" Yeah, don't. In general, don't try to *guess* what the group would do, then build your plot around that. Whenever while planning you catch yourself thinking "Then when X happens, the players will do Y and thus I can..." stop and immediately rethink it. You can try to guide them to a course of action. You can also try and force one. But these are different goals.

Comment: As an added comment from a DM'ing perspective, I will say only this; if your story hinges on a player making choice A, you should generally expect that they will make choices B-Z first, and then possibly start on the number scale, before ever making it to choice A. You can offer carrots, but you should expect that occasionally the party is going to produce a cactus in your sandbox amidst the carrots and decide they really want the peyote. :-D

Comment: Yeah last session I've learned that the hard way... People go crazy when offered so many possible solutions. I that is what I like about DnD. Thanks for you advice @VLAZ

Comment: @TheFallen0ne "*if your story hinges on a player making choice A*" I'll take the opportunity to generalise a bit: If your story hinges on *something happening*. Another *very* common problem is adding a dice roll that will determine whether the story can continue. This could be as simple as having a clue that the players have to find to investigate something where they fail. If something *has* to happen, then a) Just have it happen. b) Plan extra options and opportunities. c) Entirely remove it.